# как сделать регистрацию пользователя внутри бота pyrogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyrogram

Вопрос следующий. Хочу сделать регистрацию пользователя внутри бота, написанного на pyrogram. То есть бот запрашивает номер телефона, код подтверждения и тп в диалоге телеграмм. В написании бота нет ничего сложного, но как бот будет понимать, когда pyrogram попросил код и телефон? И как он будет передавать его самому pyrogram?

Answer (score -1):

В регистрации нет никакого смысла, потому что пользователь уже авторизирован через аккаунт Telegram.

Бот будет получать id пользователя от Telegram вместе с сообщением, используй его что бы хранить в бд данные пользователя.

> но как бот будет понимать, когда pyrogram попросил код и телефон?

Нужно хранить контекст сообщений. Для примера посмотри Dialogflow

> И как он будет передавать его самому pyrogram?

Необходимо зарегистрировать [Webhook](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook) Тогда Telegram оповестит твой сервер о новом сообщении.